# Wicket Form with DropDownChoice with Enum and CompoundPropertyModel

Tags: java, enums, wicket

I have a problem with a Java Wicket Form with a dropdownchoice like this:

```
public class SomePage extends WebPage { 
    public SomePage () {
        CompoundPropertyModel<SomeBean> properties = new CompoundPropertyModel<SomeBean>(new SomeBean());
        Form<SomeBean> form = new Form<SomeBean>("SomeBeanForm", properties) {
        //override on submit
            };
        form.add(new DropDownChoice<MyEnum>("myEnum", Lists.newArrayList(MyEnum.values()));
        add(form);
    }
}
```

SomeBean is simple like so:

```
public class SomeBean {
    private MyEnum myEnum;
    // Getter, Setter
    public SomeBean(){ 
    }
}
```

And MyEnum is:

```
public enum MyEnum { 
    CHOICE1("1"), 
    CHOICE2("2");
    private String id;
    public MyEnum(String id) {
        this.id=id;
    }
    //some methods to get/set/display id
}
```

My question is how do I set the enum in the bean using a CompoundPropertyModel? I get an exception like:

```
Could not convert value: CHOICE1 to type: MyEnum Could not find compatible converter.
```

This is caused by the face that it doesn't know how to convert anything to a MyEnum object, it requires a converter which is easy to create, but is how do I set a converter for a PropertyModel created by the CompoundPropertyModel?

Thanks for any help!

**--Edit--**

It was a wrong import for the enum, the bean and the dropdownchoice used different enums with the same name. This code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should just work: By default DropDownChoice will use the index to identify the selected enum value. No conversion is involved there.

Comment: You were right, I had two versions of the same enum in myprojects and the import used for my dropdownchoice was different than the one from my bean. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't contain entity names as component IDs that is the reason why to use the CompoundPropertyModel.

See the full code example on https://repo.twinstone.org/projects/WISTF/repos/wicket-examples-6.x/browse

**HTML Snippet:**

```
<form wicket:id="form">
    <label>Text</label>: <input type="text" wicket:id="text" /> <br/>
    <select wicket:id="choice"></select>

    <input wicket:id="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

**CODE Snippet:**

```
final IChoiceRenderer<ChoiceEnum> CHOICE_RENDERER = new ChoiceRenderer<ChoiceEnum>("description");

inal List<ChoiceEnum> ALL_CHOICES = Arrays.asList(ChoiceEnum.values());

final IModel<TextAndEnumBean> model = Model.of(new TextAndEnumBean());
final IModel<TextAndEnumBean> compoundModel = CompoundPropertyModel.of(model);

Form<TextAndEnumBean> form = new Form<>("form", compoundModel);
add(form);

form.add(new TextField<String>("text"));

form.add(new DropDownChoice<ChoiceEnum>("choice", ALL_CHOICES, CHOICE_RENDERER).setNullValid(true));

form.add(new Button("submit"));
```

**Entity Bean Code:**

```
public class TextAndEnumBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String text;

    private ChoiceEnum choice;

    public TextAndEnumBean() {
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public ChoiceEnum getChoice() {
        return choice;
    }

    public void setChoice(ChoiceEnum choice) {
        this.choice = choice;
    }

}
```

**Enum Definition Code:**

```
public enum ChoiceEnum {

    CHOICE1("choice no. 1"),
    CHOICE2("choice no. 2"),
    MY_CHOICE("example of my choice"),
    ANTOHER_CHOICE("another choice");

    private final String description;


    private ChoiceEnum(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }


}
```

Comment: You're right, in my example I did use the wrong names but not in my real code. The exception was caused by a wrong import for the enum, i had two with the same name :(

Comment: Yeah, it's a real problem. So fine, you fixed it ;-)